# As3 Convert ByteArray to Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3

Noob to As3 Bitmap stuff...

when i try to doing the following code it fails

bmd.setPixels(bmd.rect, decodeValue);

and the error message is:
Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered.

The situation is i have store the image as binary into the database by convert the byteArray and now i would like to retrieve it and convert back to image.

Just to clear this up ByteArray Need to Place into Bitmap and then you can add to the movie Clip right?

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import com.dynamicflash.util.Base64;

var loader:Loader;
var req:URLRequest;
var orig_mc:MovieClip;
var copy_mc:MovieClip;

function loaderCompleteHandler(evt:Event) {
    //swap data
    var ldr:Loader = evt.currentTarget.loader as Loader;
    var origImg:Bitmap = (ldr.content as Bitmap);
    var origBmd:BitmapData = origImg.bitmapData;
    trace(origImg.bitmapData);
    trace(origImg.width);
    trace(origImg.height);

    //Convert image byteData into Base64 String 
    var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    byteArray.writeObject(origBmd);
    var encoded:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(byteArray);
    trace("\nENCODED:\n" + encoded);
    var decoded:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(encoded);
    trace("\nDECODED:\n" + decoded.toString());

    // convert base64 string back into movieclip
    var newBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(origImg.width,origImg.height,"true",0xFFFFFFFF);
    newBmd.setPixels(origBmd.rect, decoded);**// THIS THROWS AN " Error #2030: End of file was encountered."** 
    var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(newBmd, "auto", true);
    copy_mc.addChild(image);
    copy_mc.x = origImg.width;
}

loader = new Loader();
req = new URLRequest("C:\\Data\\cutcord.jpg");
loader.load(req);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
// movieclip to display original image
orig_mc = new MovieClip();
orig_mc.addChild(loader);
addChild(orig_mc);
// movieclip to display image copy
copy_mc = new MovieClip();
addChild(copy_mc);

Anyone can help would be very appreciated :)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code :

```
   var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,img.widht,img.height);
   var byteArray:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(rect);
   var encoded:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(byteArray);

   var decoded:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(encoded);
   decoded.position = 0;
   var newBmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width,rect.height,true,0xFFFFFFFF);

   newBmd.setPixels(rect, decoded);


   var image:Bitmap = new Bitmap(newBmd, "auto", true);
   addChild(image);
```

anyway , Your idea of store string in server isnt too good ... Why You dont send ByteArray , not String ?
You can also encode bitmapData to JPG or PNG , and then send bytes to php.

Answer (score 3):

since it is an image, you have it in a BitmapData, let's say "myBmp" ... then use the following to extract all the data from BitmapData:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = myBmp.getPixels(myBmp.rect);
```

and the following to write:

```
myBmp.setPixels(myBmp.rect, bytes);
```

note that only the raw 32 bit pixel data is stored in the ByteArray, without compression, nor the dimensions of the original image.

for compression, you should refer to the corelib.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you have putted up, but i've been threw with this error: Error: Error #2030: End of file was encountered. is it because my byteArray is too large?

Comment: 90068 is the length, when i am doing a trace btw

Comment: is there a way to calculate/get original dimensions from such bytearray?